# Why doesn't std::forward preserve the lvalue-ness of this variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue

In the code below (which is run in C++20), when I call the `UseForward` function, I expect the first overload to be called (which is `template <typename T> void UseForward(T& value)`) and it does get called. Then in the body of the function I use `std::forward` which I expect to **preserve the lvalue-ness of variable `value`** and call the **copy constructor**, BUT it calls the **move constructor**. What am I missing here?

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    SomeClass(const SomeClass& other)
    {
        std::cout << "const copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    SomeClass(SomeClass&& other) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void UseForward(T& value)
{
    std::cout << "UseForward pass by reference!" << std::endl;
    auto sc = SomeClass(std::forward<T>(value));
}

template <typename T>
void UseForward(T&& value)
{
    std::cout << "UseForward pass by rvalue reference!" << std::endl;
    auto sc2 = SomeClass(std::forward<T>(value)); 
}

int main()
{
    auto sc = SomeClass();
    UseForward(sc);
}
```

Comment: `T& value` is not a forwarding (universal) reference, `T&& value` is a forwarding reference. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: You are passing incorrect type into `forward`, it should be `SomeClass(std::forward<T &>(value))` in the first overload - that's what would happen if it was (properly) used with universal reference; and `SomeClass(std::forward<T>(value));` in the second overload.

Comment: Do note that `T&& value` is not just a rvalue reference but a universal reference because `T` is a template argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment out first definition of `UseForward` and behold, both

```
UseForward(sc);
UseForward(SomeClass());
```

would say that you had passed value by rvalue reference. That's because && with cv-unqualified type T (`T&&`) in substitution context is NOT an rvalue reference but so-called *forwarding reference*, it preserves a value cathegory.

For desired effect you have to use type traits, by SFINAE or by compile-time alternatives:

```
template <typename T>
void UseForward(T&& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(value)>)
        std::cout << "UseForward pass by rvalue reference!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "UseForward pass by reference!" << std::endl;
    auto sc2 = SomeClass(std::forward<T>(value)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: you're asking it to.
`std::forward<T>(v)` where `decltype (v)` is `T&`.
See: [std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

```
template <typename T>
void UseForward(T& value) {
    std::cout << "UseForward pass by reference!" << std::endl;
    auto sc = SomeClass(std::forward<decltype (value)>(value));
}
```

[Live on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rhM948PGa)

Comment: But if we have to use decltype, then what is the purpose of std::forward? Isn't std::forward supposed to make life easier by abstracting the complex move semantics and just let us use it wherever we want?

Comment: @MohammadAlavi only thing that `std::forward<decltype (value)>(value)` does is preserving value catheogy of its argument (`value`). If you use other template paramenter, it would forward argument as a given type. There is no abstraction of semantics here, if anything, `forward` is meant for concretization and avoiding incorrect type deduction when used with forwarding reference.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have already explained, you're misusing `std::forward` inside `UseForward(T&)`, and it effectively behaves like `std::move`. Removing that function ends up calling `UseForward(T&&)`, which accepts a forwarding reference (not an rvalue reference), and `std::forward` works correctly.

#### How `std::forward` is expected to be used

It's also worth noting *why* that actually happens, and *why* `std::forward` is designed like that. `std::forward` expects either:

- `std::forward<T>(t)` where `t` is a forwarding reference, or
- `std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)` where `t` is any expression

#### How `std::forward` interacts with forwarding references

Inside `UseForward(T&&)`, when called with an lvalue of type `SomeClass`, `T` will deduce to `SomeClass&`. Due to reference collapsing, a `T&&` where `T = SomeClass&` (i.e. rvalue ref. + lvalue ref.), collapses to `SomeClass&`. This means you are calling `std::forward<SomeClass&>(SomeClass&)`, which results in an lvalue.

However, in `UseForward(T&)`, `T` will simply deduce to `SomeClass`, and you are calling `std::forward<SomeClass>(SomeClass&)`. In such a case, `std::forward` will result in an xvalue, and you end up calling the move constructor.

#### `const`-correctness can save you trouble

On a side note, you wouldn't have accidentally called the move constructor if your overloads consisted of:

- `UseForward(const T&)` and
- `UseForward(T&&)`

Even if you had misused `std::forward` inside the former function, the `const` would have prevented you from calling the move constructor. In general, you almost never want to overload between mutable lvalue/rvalue references, but rather between const lvalue references, and mutable rvalue references.

#### Conclusion

Never use `std::forward` unless working with forwarding references. Instead:

- if something is known to be an lvalue reference, don't forward at all
- if something is known to be an rvalue reference, "forward" by `std::move`
- otherwise, use `std::forward` for forwarding references as intended

```cpp
template <typename T>
void UseForward(T&& value)
{
    std::cout << "UseForward pass by forwarding reference!" << std::endl;
    auto sc2 = SomeClass(std::forward<T>(value)); 
}
```